# How can I loop this script from 1 to 50 in SPSS?

Tags: spss

```
for i=1:50

DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
QUICK CLUSTER ZlnPrice ZCPUGhz ZWeightgramm ZDisplayinch ZCameraMp
  /MISSING=LISTWISE
  /CRITERIA=CLUSTER(i) MXITER(10) CONVERGE(0)
  /METHOD=KMEANS(NOUPDATE)
  /PRINT INITIAL.

end
```

I'd like to loop CLUSTER(i) from 1 to 50. How can I solve this problem? I'd like to avoid brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. One is to make a macro function.

```
define !myloops()
!do !i = 1 !to 50
QUICK CLUSTER ZlnPrice ZCPUGhz ZWeightgramm ZDisplayinch ZCameraMp
  /MISSING=LISTWISE
  /CRITERIA=CLUSTER(i) MXITER(10) CONVERGE(0)
  /METHOD=KMEANS(NOUPDATE)
  /PRINT INITIAL.
!doend
!enddefine.

Select and Run that - read into processor memory.

Then issue commands.
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
!myloops.

You're there.
```